# How to write a function that set first element to an array?

Tags: javascript

I was asked to write a function setFirstElement that takes an array and an arbitrary variable. The variable should be inserted as the first element in the array. The array should be returned.

My code was like this:

```
 function setFirstElement (arr, elem){

      let arr = [];
      arr[0] = elem;


      return arr;

 }
```

With this code, I've encountered an Uncaught Syntax Error, saying that identifier 'arr' has already been declared.

**Is it because I declared the array with 'let'? Can anyone help with this error?**

Later, I revised my code by removing the 'let' and it works. But I am still confused about why it works after I removed 'let' from the previous code.

```
 function setFirstElement (arr, elem){
  
      arr[0]= elem;

      return arr;
```

}

Comment: the **arr** variable enters the function body via its parameters. Anything written inside **()** are parameters and don't need to be declared again, just like **elem**

Comment: The requirement was for the function to take an array, and a variable. You don't need to create a new array in the function with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword "let" declares something new. So, if you are passing in a variable named "arr", and ALSO declaring a new variable by the same name, "arr," this will produce an error.

So, when you look at this error:
"SyntaxError: Cannot declare a let variable twice: 'arr'."
It's telling you that you're trying to make the same thing with the same name, twice, and that's not allowed.

When you remove "let," it works because now javascript knows you're talking about the variable "arr" that you're passing in, and not some new variable by the same name.